# Can i change an item in a list from another list?

Tags: list, sharepoint

I´ve created a list in SharePoint. What i´ll like to do is create another list, and retrieve some information from one list to my new one, and be able to change the input data from list A in a single line of text.

So lets say, list A is PopStar, with columns like Genre "Rock", HairColor "Red" and GrammyCount "2".

In list B i only want textboxes to show whats in list A and be able to change (update) them, for example Genre to "Pop", HairColor to "Black" and GrammyCont to "8" ?

Is this possible?

i´m using office 365

Comment: so you wabt to fetch data from List A and want to show in some form/grid and after update you want to save it to List B??

Comment: Hi! Yea, basically it´s three lists. List A is a pure information list, it doesn't create anything . List B is used as a form in nintex and can create new things and add them to list A. In list C (the one you refers to list b) is the list that i just want to retrieve information from list A, (stuff added from list B) and i would like to have the input in textboxes, so when i change/update the values i´ll do it in 'single line of text' columns. Does it make any sense..?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve exactly what you want you will require either a Workflow or an Event Receiver, however I assume you won't feel confident by struggling with such approaches, furthermore, there are some workarounds that could be very close to your requirement and maybe are even better solutions than the approach you suggest, in terms of maintenance, growth and upgrade.

I suggest to review topics like "SharePoint parent/child list webparts connections" or "sharepoint edit form add child items", here are two videos of which you can get some ideas.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PWIxk6rF-A

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5CdjfLONgE

Take in count that you can do more than what is displayed in the videos, by example in the Edit Form you could add a webpart to display the Quick Edit View (Grid View) of the related list so the values can be edited in the same Form and thus removing the need to navigate to a second window.

Comment: Thank you very much! Much appreciated